# How to get user id from collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to give a role to users who reacted on a message. In which I am facing some issues.
I can't get user's id or username. Please find the code below:

```
               let suser = message.member;


               const filterv = (reaction, userv) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && userv.id != suser.id && userv.id != "692755575418650654"

               m.awaitReactions(filterv, {max: 1})
               .then(cc => {

                console.log(cc.forEach((reaction => reaction.users.forEach(console.log))))    
                m.delete()

               })
               .catch(console.log);
```

Above code returns `undefined`
what should I do instead of
`console.log(cc.forEach((reaction => reaction.users.forEach(console.log))))`
to get id(s) from the map

```
users:
Collection [Map] {
  },
  '681898825463627866' => User {
    id: '681898825463627866',
    username: 'ayetest',
    discriminator: '2219',
    avatar: null,
    bot: false,
    lastMessageID: null,
    lastMessage: null
  }
}
```

I am trying to do something like this(code below) but can't get user from the collection but instead getting `userv` is not defined

```
let srole = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === args[0])

let suser = message.member;

const filterv = (reaction, userv) => reaction.emoji.name === ':white_check_mark:' && userv.id != suser.id && userv.id != "692755575418650654"

m.awaitReactions(filterv, {max: 1})
.then(collection => {
userv.addRole(srole.id) 
m.delete()
})
.catch(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have an easier time using [`createReactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) instead of `awaitReactions`.